# How to create a templated composite control with a behavior

Tags: asp.net, controltemplate, composite-controls

I'm trying to create a templated composite control that would work in a similar fashion as the "PasswordRecovery" control of ASP.Net.

By that, I mean that the user can define its own template but, by using pre-defined controls ID, it defines which field is, say the e-mail address, and which button is the one to send the e-mail.

I've tried to look at the documentation for templated web server controls, but I can't find anything talking about adding a behavior to those controls.

Alternatively, is there a way to change the behavior of the PasswordRecovery completely? I would like to send an e-mail with a one-time URL to change the password instead of the common behavior of that control.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I answered a related question:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/11700540/1268570

But in this answer I will go deeper.

I will post a templated server control with design support and with custom behavior:

#### Container code

```
[ToolboxItem(false)]
public class TemplatedServerAddressContainer : WebControl, INamingContainer
{
    public string Address { get; protected set; }

    public TemplatedServerAddressContainer(string address)
    {
        this.Address = address;
    }
}
```

- The above control will be in charge to keep the data you want to **send to the control as OUTPUT**. That will be the control you will instantiate your template in

#### Server Control

```
[DefaultProperty("Address")]
[ToolboxItem(true)]
[ToolboxData("<{0}:TemplatedServerAddressControl runate=server></{0}:TemplatedServerAddressControl>")]
[Designer(typeof(TemplatedServerAddressDesigner))]
//[ToolboxBitmap(typeof(TemplatedServerAddressControl), "")]
[Description("My templated server control")]
[ParseChildren(true)]
public class TemplatedServerAddressControl : WebControl
{
    private TemplatedServerAddressContainer addressContainer;

    [Bindable(true)]
    [Localizable(true)]
    [DefaultValue(null)]
    [Description("The custom address")]
    [Category("Apperance")]
    [Browsable(true)]
    public string Address
    {
        get
        {
            return (this.ViewState["Address"] ?? string.Empty).ToString();
        }
        set
        {
            this.ViewState["Address"] = value;
        }
    }

    [Browsable(false)]
    [DefaultValue(null)]
    [Description("Address template")]
    [PersistenceMode(PersistenceMode.InnerProperty)]
    [TemplateContainer(typeof(TemplatedServerAddressContainer))]
    [TemplateInstance(TemplateInstance.Multiple)]
    public ITemplate AddressTemplate { get; set; }

    [Browsable(false)]
    [DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Hidden)]
    public TemplatedServerAddressContainer AddressContainer
    {
        get
        {
            this.EnsureChildControls();

            return this.addressContainer;
        }
        internal set
        {
            this.addressContainer = value;
        }
    }

    public override ControlCollection Controls
    {
        get
        {
            this.EnsureChildControls();

            return base.Controls;
        }
    }

    public override void DataBind()
    {
        this.CreateChildControls();
        this.ChildControlsCreated = true;

        base.DataBind();
    }

    protected override void CreateChildControls()
    {
        this.Controls.Clear();

        if (this.AddressTemplate != null)
        {
            this.addressContainer = new TemplatedServerAddressContainer(this.Address);

            this.AddressTemplate.InstantiateIn(this.addressContainer);
            this.Controls.Add(this.addressContainer);
        }
    }

    protected override bool OnBubbleEvent(object source, EventArgs args)
    {
        if (args is CommandEventArgs)
        {
            var commandArgs = args as CommandEventArgs;

            switch (commandArgs.CommandName)
            {
                case "DoSomething":
                    // place here your custom logic
                    this.Page.Response.Write("Command bubbled");
                    return true;
            }
        }

        return base.OnBubbleEvent(source, args);
    }
}
```

- The `public string Address` property is used **as control INPUT**, you can create all the input properties you need in order to execute your task.
- `public ITemplate AddressTemplate { get; set; }` This represents the template of your control. The name you give to this property will be the name used in the page's markup as the name of your template
- `public TemplatedServerAddressContainer AddressContainer` This property is just for designer support
- In order to create correctly the child controls you need to override the following methods and properties: `Controls`, `DataBind` and `CreateChildControls`
- Overriding the `OnBubbleEvent`, you will be able to react to specific events coming from the control.

#### Designer support

```
public class TemplatedServerAddressDesigner : ControlDesigner
{
    private TemplatedServerAddressControl controlInstance;

    public override void Initialize(IComponent component)
    {
        this.controlInstance = (TemplatedServerAddressControl)component;

        base.Initialize(component);
    }

    public override string GetDesignTimeHtml()
    {
        var sw = new StringWriter();
        var htmlWriter = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
        var controlTemplate = this.controlInstance.AddressTemplate;

        if (controlTemplate != null)
        {
            this.controlInstance.AddressContainer = new TemplatedServerAddressContainer(
                this.controlInstance.Address
                );
            controlTemplate.InstantiateIn(this.controlInstance.AddressContainer);

            this.controlInstance.DataBind();

            this.controlInstance.RenderControl(htmlWriter);
        }

        return sw.ToString();
    }
}
```

#### ASPX markup

```
<%@ Register Assembly="Msts" Namespace="Msts.Topics.Chapter07___Server_Controls.Lesson02___Server_Controls" TagPrefix="address" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
    <address:TemplatedServerAddressControl runat="server" ID="addressControl1">
        <AddressTemplate>
            <b>
                Address:
            </b>
            <u>
                <asp:Literal Text="<%# Container.Address %>" runat="server" />
            </u>
            <asp:Button Text="text" runat="server" OnClick="Unnamed_Click" ID="myButton" />
            <br />
            <asp:Button Text="Command bubbled" runat="server" CommandName="DoSomething" OnClick="Unnamed2_Click1" />
        </AddressTemplate>
    </address:TemplatedServerAddressControl>
</asp:Content>
```

#### ASPX code behind

```
public partial class TemplatedServerAddress : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.addressControl1.Address = "Super Cool";
        this.DataBind();
    }

    protected void Unnamed_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Response.Write("From custom button" + DateTime.Now.ToString());
    }

    protected void Unnamed2_Click1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Response.Write("From command button " + DateTime.Now.ToString());
    }
}
```

- Notice how you can set control's properties without problems in the correct event: `this.addressControl1.Address = "Super Cool";`
- Notice how your control can handle custom events `this.Response.Write("From custom button" + DateTime.Now.ToString());`
- And finally, to indicate to your control that you *want to perform something*, just create a button with the command name exposed by your control like this: `<asp:Button Text="Command bubbled" runat="server" CommandName="DoSomething" OnClick="Unnamed2_Click1" />` optionally, your button can contain an event handler that will be handled prior to bubbling the event.

[I uploaded this code sample completely functional to my GitHub for reference](https://github.com/jupaol/LearningProjects/tree/master/VS%202012/src/WebForms/MSTS%2070-515/Msts/Topics/Chapter07%20-%20Server%20Controls/Lesson02%20-%20Server%20Controls)

Comment: Wow, that's an awesome answer, thanks! The only thing I still miss is how you actually get back data. For example, if I want that the user can add a textbox with a specific ID and get back the information contained in this textbox in the eventhandler.

Comment: You accomplish that by exposing public properties at the control level. The `public string Address` property is used as control INPUT, you can create all the input properties you need in order to execute your task. And then just set those properties on the page like you would set any other control property

Comment: No, what I meant is, for example, say instead of having just a literal like in your example, you have a textbox. Then, you want that the user adds some information in that textbox and you want that the event checks the value of the textbox. Since it's a templated control, how do you get the value of that textbox?

Comment: You could do something like this:                 `var t = this.addressContainer as TemplatedServerAddressContainer;
                var tt = t.FindControl("txt") as TextBox;
                tt.Text = "jdiajdia";`
In the `CreateChildControls` method after you instantiate your template and after you add it to the page. However this is not the recommended approach. If you want to pass data to the control, you should expose public control properties

Answer (score 0):

How about templated User Controls (as opposed to templated Server controls).

There's an MSDN tutorial here on templated User Controls: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/36574bf6(v=vs.100).aspx

If you wanted pre-defined IDs, then you could use the `FindControl()` method to extract the controls from the templates and then attach whatever click events, etc.. you need to.

e.g.

```
protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  // if a message template has been defined, check for the reset button
  if(MessageTemplate != null)
  {
    // attempt to grab the reset password button
    Button btnResetPassword = MessageTemplate.FindControl("btnResetPassword ") as Button;

    // if the reset password button has been declared, attach the click event             
    if(btnResetPassword != null)
      btnResetPassword .Click += btnResetPassword_Click;  // attach click event
  }
}

protected void btnResetPassword_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  // reset password behaviour here
}
```

The code above isn't complete/tested, but just to give an idea of what I mean.  Not sure if that's the kind of thing you mean?

Comment: I can't really use the User Control as I want to add that in a separate library, and User Controls have to be in the same library to work. But actually, this idea should work as well for server controls.